# How can I programmatically verify if a CYGWIN app is installed in a SH script?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, cygwin, exim

Here's the situation :

I am writing a SH deployment script that will deploy a website with an RSYNC command in CYGWIN.  After the installation, I want to send an e-mail to the development team to say that a deployment has been made with some details.  I will use "exim" to send the mail from CYGWIN.

The thing is that, exim is only optional when installing CYGWIN and I would like to quit my SH script if it's not installed.  Any idea to check in UNIX (and working in CYGWIN) if an app is installed in a script ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# bash script (should also work with sh)
# someprog must be on the path for type to find it
if type -p "someprog"
then
    echo "it's there"
else
    echo "it isn't"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, that looked easy finally but didn't know the command :)

Answer (score 2):

Specifically to check for 'exim',  execute

```
exim -bV
```

On my Cygwin it gives an output like,

```
Exim version 4.69 #1 built 28-Jan-2008 21:59:08
Copyright (c) University of Cambridge 2006
Probably GDBM (native mode)
Support for: crypteq iconv() PAM OpenSSL Content_Scanning
Lookups: lsearch wildlsearch nwildlsearch iplsearch dbm dbmnz dnsdb dsearch ldap
    ldapdn ldapm passwd
Authenticators: cram_md5 plaintext spa
Routers: accept dnslookup ipliteral manualroute queryprogram redirect
Transports: appendfile/maildir/mailstore/mbx autoreply pipe smtp
Size of off_t: 8
Configuration file is /etc/exim.conf
```

From the 'exim' manual on '**exim -bV**',

> This  option causes Exim to write the current version number, compilation
>                    number, and compilation date of the exim binary to the  standard  output.
>                    It  also  lists  the DBM library this is being used, the optional modules
>                    (such as specific lookup types), the drivers that  are  included  in  the
>                    binary, and the name of the run time configuration file that is in use.
>
> As  part  of  its operation, -bV causes Exim to read and syntax check its
>                    configuration file. However, this is a static check only. It cannot check
>                    values that are to be expanded. For example, although a misspelt ACL verb
>                    is detected, an error in the verb's arguments is not. You cannot rely  on
>                    -bV  alone  to discover (for example) all the typos in the configuration;
>                    some realistic testing is needed. The -bh and  -N  options  provide  more
>                    dynamic testing facilities.

---

Comparing with the **`type`** and **`which`** checks.

**type** is a shell builtin command. It indicates how a name will be interpreted by the shell if used as a command. The **`-p`** option causes it to return the name of the disk file that would be executed if the command was issued.

**which** simply searches for an executable by the given name in the search `PATH` using the same `bash` algorithm.

**Either of these will return true if someone puts an executable file called by the same name in the path. You should be more careful about invoking commands from a script, if security is a concern.**

It may be prudent to know what you are running.
Of course, I can also implement a shell script called `exim` that will return the above input on `-bV`; and mess-up things in the background -- what is your level of paranoia?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'which' command. 
It will return you the location of the program or nothing if not present.

Answer (score 0):

To alleviate the security concerns that **nik** brought up you can check the location of the executable against an expected list of locations:

```
case $(type -p someprog) in

    /usr/bin/someprog \
    | /bin/someprog \
    | /usr/local/someprog)

        echo "Valid location";; 
    *)
        echo "Invalid location";;
esac
```